# Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type '[any Protocol]'

Tags: swift, protocols

I have this relatively simple setup and the goal is to store different types in the list inside MyListView but all the types will conform to a certain protocol.

```
protocol HasString {
    var text: String { get set }
}

struct ItemType1: HasString {
    var text: String
}

struct ItemType2: HasString {
    var text: String
    var number: Int
}


struct MyListView: View {
    var list: [any HasString]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<list.count, id: \.self) {
            index in
            Text(list[index].text)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView<T: HasString>: View {
    let type1 = ItemType1(text: "text1")
    let type2 = ItemType2(text: "text2", number: 1)
    
    var body: some View {
        let list = [type1, type2] //compile error shows here
        MyListView(list: list)
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type '[any HasString]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a really minor thing. The variable `list` was of type `[HasString]` and all I had to do was to add `as [any HasString]` behind the list and the error went away.

```
let list = [type1, type2] as [any HasString]
```

Comment: Would not it be better to annotate the type like this?
`let list: [HasString] = [type1, type2]`

Answer (score 0):

`type1` and `type2` is a different struct and list of them `[type1, type2]` is Any, and `[any HasString]` can not convert. You need to cast them with `HasString`:

```
 let type1 : HasString = ItemType1(text: "text1")
 let type2 : HasString = ItemType2(text: "text2", number: 1)
```